# Want to share the same set of Active Record models for two databases based on primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have one set of ActiveRecord models and two databases (with the same schema) I want to use them against.  I would like to switch the connection on the fly based on the primary key of the parent model.  The alternative would be to duplicate the set of models and have them inherit from a different superclass whose connection is the other db (http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2006/01/sharing_externa.html).  Basically, I am building an interface which will allow users to compare similar data in the two databases.  However, sometimes the data the users will be comparing will come from the same database.  This data will be read-only as I don't need to write anything to either db.

Answer (score 1):

Right now we are looking into `octopus` for database sharding, maybe that could be useful for you too?

https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

Comment: Octopus seems to work perfectly! Had some configuration problems (needed to manually set the development environment and call Octopus.config in my environment.rb), but once those were figured out things look pretty good. Also, the only way I can get it to work correctly is to call Octopus.using(:db) and pass in the block.

Comment: Glad it helped! BTW: part of SO etiquette is upvoting and/or accepting helpful answers, so if you plan on becoming part of this community (which I highly recommend), you should start doing that.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I actually already tried and it told me I need a 15 reputation.  Once I get there you'll get my vote.

Comment: @Trey: ah, forgot about that. It's not that I care so badly, I just recently saw an influx of people to SO who don't seem to "get it", so I tend to post comments early. No offense intended and welcome to SO! :-)

Comment: +1 Looks like a very useful gem. They haven't released a new version for almost a year, but you could point to the git repo in your Gemfile. Note that bug #88 is still unresolved, but there is a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelKohl btw, have you actually used this in production? What version of rails and octopus?

Comment: We used it with Rails 2.3 and Postgres 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. I have not tried it:

http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections/

The page admits that issues have been found in version 1.0.0. It also doesn't seem as "transparent" as octopus (mentioned in the other answer), which can use a different connection by wrapping a block around existing code.